# How to run webpacker compiled javascript only when page is loaded on rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

Where to put `window.onload`, to get in every page in rails 6 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is:

Add a folder `app/javascript/js` then add a file `app/javascript/js/main.js`

as I am using turbolinks I add code to that file like:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    ....
}
```

or if not using turbolinks:

```
window.addEventListener('load' , function() {
    ....
}
```

then you include this in your pack file by adding this line:

```
import '../js/main'
```

to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`